# How to force down div from floating div

Tags: html

I have following floating divs:

```
+---------------+ +-----------+
|               | |           |
|               | |   Div-B   |
|               | |Float:left |
|               | |           |
|     Div-A     | |           |
|  Float: left  | +-----------+
|- - - - - - - -|-+-----------+
|               | |           |
|     Ext       | |  Div-C    |
|               | |           |
|- - - - - - - -|-+-----------+
|               |
+---------------+
```

As you can see I have three number of divs in where Div-A and Div-B float to the left. As Div-C (Without Ext area) has no floating property, it jumps to the blank space of the right side of Div-A. So, the left border of Div-C should be adjacent to the right border of Div-A. In practical, this is happening too, i.e text inside Div-C is starting from the right border of Div-A. But in Google-Chrome browser, in developer tool, I can see that actually the left border of Div-C is staying adjacent to the left border of Div-A.
My question is why Google-Chrome is showing left border of Div-C adjacent to the left border of Div-A?

Comment: Take it easy and make an example in http://www.jsfiddle.net for this, man...

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct behavior according to CSS2.1 spec [for floats](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats):

> Since a float is not in the flow, non-positioned block boxes created
>   before and after the float box flow vertically *as if the float did not
>   exist*. However, the current and subsequent line boxes created next to
>   the float are shortened as necessary to make room for the margin box
>   of the float.

So floats don't influence the borders of normal blocks and affect only text. The block still takes the full accessible width of the container and the float just overlaps it. However, the situation changes for the blocks that establish [new block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting) (e.g. those with display:table or overflow:hidden). These blocks may shorten themselves to the width of their text (and do so in all browsers, although the spec doesn't strictly require this).

Comment: Because of this reason, I believe the only way to get Div-C to the position desired is by making it's position absolute and positioning it manually or making all objects grid based or something similar. See http://jsfiddle.net/ECp9X/

Answer (score 0):

If there is enough text in div-c to go past the bottom of div-a, it would wrap around the bottom of div-a and then be adjacent to its left border.

Comment: No there is no enough text in Div-C. It is not wrapping text around bottom of Div-A. Actually it is working well in web page. But I am talking about Developer tool of Google Chrome. In developer tool (like firebug in firefox), it is showing the left border of Div-C adjacent to the left border of Div-A.